# How to align vertically divs?

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

Could you help me align vertically (on blue background) text and icons (fb, etc) ?
I tried to use vertical-align, display:table, etc. But it didn't solve my problem.

http://tinyurl.com/pe4avff

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't use display and vertical-align properties in the right way.

Use the following styles:

```
.align {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    ...
}

.vertical {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also notice that this is a common practice for vertical alignment, but not the only one.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
.vertical {
display: table-row;
line-height: 2em;
}
```

Which is basically setting line-height of the text in your div to the same value as your divs height.

Comment: Would solve in this case, but can be problematic in a multi-line scenario

Answer (score 0):

Remove float: left from CSS classes bar-menu-left, bar-menu-right and bar-icons.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to **vertically** align all text and icons you should remove

`float:left;` from the `.bar-menu-left`, `.bar-menu-right` and `.bar-icons` classes.